# How to add tags to mailchimp with freeform_next

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, mailchimp, solspace-freeform-next

i have a few newsletter signup forms (mailchimp) on this site. We need to differentiate the subscribers to different forms in mailchimp. We do that via tags. How can i add the tags to the newsletter subscribe form? I currently have a hidden field called "tags" with the id of the tag but that doesn't seem to get sent to mailchimp

Answer (score 0):

Jelle - do you have fields created in Mailchimp to hold the "tags" data?

I've done similar things with Mailchimp, here's what I did:

1. Create a new free text input field in Mailchimp to hold the tags data
2. Add the field to your form code in Mailchimp's form editor and save
3. Copy form code, add to your site, and tweak so the tags field is hidden and you write tags data to it using EE code